# Pass script to background using script itself

Tags: bash, shell-script, busybox

It is possible to do something like this:

```
nohup ./run.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Which sends the process to background, discards its output and allows us to close terminal.

Is there any possible way to do that using the script itself? I mean, I would execute this:

```
./run.sh
```

and somewhere inside the script, can we do something like this:

```
nohup "$0" > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

So that when the script is run, it will act same as above?

I suppose we can have two separate scripts for this. However, is it possible to do in a single script?

I'm asking because the script will be called from the system, and I don't want to change how the system calls the script, I'd prefer I change how the script is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement this if you have something to decide if the script should execute itself in the background or if it already is the one in the background, e.g. a command line argument.

Assuming you normally call your script

```
./run.sh
```

you could add a command line argument, e.g. `bg` to tell the script that it already is in the second execution, so it will not recursively call itself endless times (or until the system resources have been used up).

```
./run.sh bg
```

You can implement it like this

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "bg" ]
then

    # do the normal work

else

    nohup "$0" bg > /dev/null 2>&1 &

fi
```

Comment: Great, that works for me!